# RCheck: Data with usage in documentation object 'info_data' but not in code

Tags: r, cran

so in my project I have in the description file `LazyData: TRUE`. In my data folder I have a dataframe stored as `info_data.rda`. So, I know want to document this data:

```
#' @title Data info_data
#' @description Test info
#' @format A data frame with the following columns:
#' \itemize{
#'   \item{id:}{ID }
#'   \item{number:}{number}
#' }
#' @source MyPackage
#' @usage data(info_data)
"info_data"
```

So, as soon as I run `rcheck` I get: `Data with usage in documentation object 'info_data' but not in code: 'info_data'`

I've found this similar post [Warning: “Variables with usage in documentation object ‘FANG’ but not in code:”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396392/warning-variables-with-usage-in-documentation-object-fang-but-not-in-code), but I should have made everything correct actually. Do you have any other suggestions?

One thing to mention. During rcheck, I see the line:

```
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
```

Is this related?